# JBoss connection configuration for LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, jboss7.x

I want to use JBoss AS 7.1 server's connection pooling to configure the LDAP server. I will be writing a java program to connect to LDAP server configured in the 
above step and retrieve the user information. The java class will be a part of war file I will be deploying to the same JBoss server later on. Can somebody help 
with what xml file in which location needs to be modified to have the LDAP information and also a small code snippet in java class that reads the configurations and 
connects to the LDAP server. I ahve something very simple in a java file which connects to the LDAP server and gets the info. as shown below:

```
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();  
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Manager, dc=maxcrc,dc=com");  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");  
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389");
```

Also if I have the password encrypted in the config file is there a utility provided by JBoss framework to decrypt the password while connecting to the server or 
should I write the method in my java class to decrypt and send it across. I won't be using JBoss LDAP authentication. I saw some posts with login-config files
which won't help my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm out of time to test now but I believe you need to use an ExternalContext to achieve your goal.

See this link: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/Additional_Naming_MBeans-org.jboss.naming.ExternalContext_MBean.html

Then see this: https://community.jboss.org/thread/175856

I really believe this is the way :)

Best,
-- Mauricio